# What is an example of a Monte-Carlo algorithm for finding a Hamiltonian path?

Tags: probabilistic-algorithms, hamiltonian-path, monte-carlo

I've recently been made aware that there exist Monte-Carlo algorithm(s?) for determining whether a Hamiltonian path exists in a graph. I am struggling to figure out how it would work. What is the random element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several such algorithms for various graph problems; for Hamiltonian path one example is due to Björklund [1]. These algorithms are often algebraic and the "random element" stems from the application of the [Schwartz–Zippel lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz%E2%80%93Zippel_lemma). Usually, the algorithms work so that the graph property we are interested in is somehow represented as a (multivariate) polynomial with the property that that a solution exists precisely when the polynomial is not identically zero.

---

[1] [Björklund, Andreas. "Determinant sums for undirected hamiltonicity." SIAM Journal on Computing 43.1 (2014): 280-299.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.0541.pdf)